# Are there other ways to pass parameters to javascript other than document.location.hash?

Tags: javascript

I am looking for an alternative(s) that allow variables to be pulled in from the URL to be used in scripts on the page.

Answer (score 2):

The query string can also be used for this.

Here's a little helper:

```
var getQueryValue = (function () {

    var populated, queryArray = [];

    return function (key) {
        populated || populate();
        return queryArray[key];
    }

    function populate ()
    {
        var pair, chunks, l, i = 0, queryString = window.location.href.split('?')[1];
        populated = true;
        if ( ! queryString ) return;

        chunks = queryString.split('&');
        l = chunks.length;

        for ( ; i < l; i++  ) {
            pair = chunks[i].split('=');
            queryArray[ pair[0] ] = pair[1];
        }
    }
}());
```

Use it as follows:

```
var page = getQueryValue('page');
```

Comment: @JonathanLonowski - No particular reason. I think I once bumped into some situation that didn't support `location.search`. BTW, I never figured out why `location.search` returns a leading `?`. Kind of defeats the purpose. Given that I'll anyhow have to get rid of the `?`, `href` is just shorter than `search` :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use cookies.

Comment: Cookies are not transported in URLs though.

Comment: No they aren't, but if all the pages are under the same domain, each page can access cookie variables.